# What's wrong on the following using CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, java-8

I am new to CompletableFuture,
here is a simple one I would like to try

```
 CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( ()-> {System.out.println("async");});
```

When I try to compile, it gave the error

```
Error:(23, 26) java: no suitable method found for supplyAsync(()->{ Syst[...]"); })
    method java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.<U>supplyAsync(java.util.function.Supplier<U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) U
        (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
          missing return value))
    method java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.<U>supplyAsync(java.util.function.Supplier<U>,java.util.concurrent.Executor) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

I am wondering what's wrong with the above?

Comment: Well you're not returning anything - what sort of "supplier" do you think you're passing?

Comment: You are missing the return https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-

Comment: You should use `CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.println("async"));` instead.

Comment: does not compile for this: no instance of type variable U so that void conforms to U

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like it says in the error message:

> missing return value

Suppliers have to return a value. Try:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> {System.out.println("async"); return null;});
```

or, like Flown points out, use `runAsync`:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(()-> System.out.println("async"));
```

Comment: It works, but is there a way not using "return null"

Comment: Sure: return anything you like. But to repeat: "Suppliers have to return something". If it doesn't return something, it's a `Runnable`, not a `Supplier`.

Comment: @Adam Lee: if you insist on using `supplyAsync` despite not supplying anything, you can use `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> System.out.append("async\n"))`